# Managing multiple navigator in Vaadin 8

Tags: navigation, vaadin, vaadin8

Currently I have 2 navigators in my project. 
First navigator's ViewDisplay is UI and second navigators ViewDisplay is part of UI.
I have created the second navigator for navigating through my side menu. As I want to change only the contents of selected menu items.

But the problem is I didn't find any way to tell vaadin when to use which navigator. Plus how vaadin manages multiple navigator? What is the lifecycle of navigators?

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigator` is tied to `UI` and it is one to one relationship in Vaadin 7 and 8. So it is not possible to have multiple `Navigator`s within one `UI`. This limitation can be hacked of course by using multiple `UI`'s. So you need to implement the subview as its own `UI` and embbed that to master `UI`.

The best way to embbed the sub UI is to use [BrowserFrame](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/BrowserFrame.html) component or [Embedded UI add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/embedded-ui) which reduces need for boiler plate code. You can find more info from blog post [Microservices and Vaadin UIs](https://vaadin.com/blog/microservices-and-vaadin-uis).

Vaadin was aware of this limitation, and in the new Vaadin 10+ platform series `Navigator` has been replaced with `Router` concept, that supports subnavigation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you please tell me how can embed a sub UI to master UI?

Comment: Thanks for additional question, I revised the answer to included that information too.